# Could I use multiple materials in Skybox?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unityscript

I'm using Unity and making a 3D program that runs in a 2D environment.

My problem is this, I want to use 2 materials for Skybox Material.

The one is the asset I bought, they offer beautiful skies and weather that changes based on your settings.

And I wanna overlay my custom mountain material.

So in the end, I want to get a horizon that shows the ridge and sky together on the screen.

I also attach one photo that I described! [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANmwP.png)

Thanks for reading my problem!

Should I finally open the Shader code?!

It must be hard, but if that is the only way I can solve than I'll try my best.

But Please share if there are any other solutions to you!!!

Comment: You will probably have to make your own custom skybox shader. It is not so difficult, [here you have some simple examples](https://github.com/keijiro/UnitySkyboxShaders) where you can start. Probably you want to support textures for both your mountains and your sky and blend them in some way.